# How Can I retrieve my code when notepad++ crash

Tags: notepad++

I had write my code and suddenly notepad++ crash and all my codes are missing. How can Iretrieve the file? can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature in Notepad++. Check out `Settings > Preferences > Backup`. If you have `Session Snapshot` enabled. You can browse to the `Backup Path`, and retrieve your code. If you don't have it enabled. You might be out of luck. This can be a lesson learned and you can enable it from now on!

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I had finally retrieved the backup file.